# Is it possible to change an object which was originally created as a subclass object to another subclass object?

Tags: java, class, oop, subclass

For example, I have a Class (Account) and 2 subclasses (BasicAccount and PremiumAccount).

If I create an object like this

```
Account account1 = new BasicAccount();
```

Is it possible to change account1 subclass to PremiumAccount?

Comment: You can assign e.g. `account1 = new PremiumAccount()`; but there's no way to change an instance of `BasicAccount` into a `PremiumAccount`.

Comment: There is no builtin way, *you* have to code it. E.g. `account1 = new PremiumAccount(account1)` with a proper constructor if you need some fields retained.

Comment: No: if both `BasicAccount` and `PremiumAccount` are direct subclasses of `Account` then a `BasicAccount` is-not-a `PremiumAccount`. You could *build* a `PremiumAccount` *from* a `BasicAccount`.

Comment: if an account can be functionally upgraded to or downgraded from a premium account, you can consider to define premium as an attribute (`private boolean isPremium;`) of your account and not as a subclass.

Comment: This is a use-case for a design-pattern like state-pattern or decorator-pattern, not inheritance. Being "premium" or "basic" are states of an account, not more specific types.

Comment: No, and one of the reasons is how the memory allocation works for objects which inherit other objects. What you could do is to programatically transform one object into another.

Comment: @akuzminykh *shrug* Implementation detail; there's no reason this couldn't be handled via OOP. While I might be more inclined to have a composed `AccountHandler` (or whatever) that is responsible for basic/premium details, the differences between a "basic" and "premium" account are more than just a flag--there's likely behavior and/or values that are also changed. Scattering state checks throughout the code negates one value proposition of OOP.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think that using a design-pattern is not OO. And there won't be as many checks as you might expect; there are design-patterns that avoid those, e.g. the strategy-pattern. I want to point out that using inheritance here is the cause of the problem. It's wrong (or at least questionable) to use inheritance to represent states. It leads to problems like this one. I once had a somewhat similar [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408246/polymorphism-case-study-design-pattern-for-morphing).

Comment: @akuzminykh That it was implemented wrong doesn’t make the *decision* wrong, although as I said, I likely wouldn’t use inheritance either. You keep saying basic vs premium is a state—that’s an assumption you’re making based on information neither of us have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, that’s fundamentally not possible.

A practical solution to the underlying problem is via the [envelope–letter pattern](https://www.cs.vu.nl/%7Eeliens/online/tutorials/objects/patterns/handle.html) (also known as handle–body idiom).

That is, you create a *wrapper class* that implements the common interface and dispatches all methods to an instance variable which can be reassigned.

At minimum, this would look as follows:

```
class AccountWrapper implements Account {
    private Account instance;

    private AccountWrapper(Account instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static AccountWrapper createBasicAccount() {
        return new AccountWrapper(new BasicAccount());
    }

    public static AccountWrapper createPremiumAccount() {
        return new AccountWrapper(new PremiumAccount());
    }

    public void upgrade() {
        if (instance instanceof PremiumAccount) throw new InvalidStateException();
        this.instance = new PremiumAccount(instance); // copy state
    }

    // … implement Account methods and forward to `instance`.
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
final AccountWrapper account = AccountWrapper.createBasicAccount();
// …
account.upgrade();
```